# Request returns 200 on Postman but 404 testing on website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have built a simple Api that returns a few places with associated data, and everything works fine, but i have a more specific research method that also is working fine in testing phase using Postman. I've made a few requests in my web application and they receive expected result, but now I've come to the point where I need to call this method I made, which returns proper response on Postman but 404 on my web application when I log the response message.

This is how I make my request:

```html
<script>
    function getCities() {
        var selectedRegion = document.getElementById("region_select").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowCitiesByRegion", "ClientTourism")',
            accepts: "/",
            data: {
                regionId: selectedRegion
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#city_select_div').html(data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
              console.log(response.responseText);
            },
        });
        console.log(selectedRegion);
    }
</script>
```

This request calls up my controller, which looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowCitiesByRegion(int regionId)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID DA REGIAO-" + regionId);
    List<City> cities = new List<City>();
    HttpClient httpClient = _api.Initial();
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("​api​/Cities​/region_cities​/region=" + regionId);
    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var response = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        cities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City>>(response);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cidades-" + cities);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Erro" + httpResponseMessage);
    }
    return PartialView(cities);
}
```

This controller calls up the api and it never gets a `SuccessStatusCode`.
My API console run never indicates it is receiving the request, except when its coming from Postman.
I've narrowed the problem to the request making, although I checked every variable and every data is passing through view to controller as expected. It returns this response message:
[image: RequestResponseMessage]

Cant seem to figure why I am always getting 404 while doing this request from my web application.

Comment: Please do not mix blocking and non-blocking async I/O calls. Please try to use non-blocking. So instead of this: `httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` please use `await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: I dont know how that makes sense, by removing Result from the httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  and reading the result in the next line after the readAsStringAsync works perfectly fine. Appreciated very much about your tipo @PeterCsala

Comment: do you wish to create a post where you capture the solution or should I do that?

Comment: @PeterCsala you can do it and I'll check for it as result. Since I know for no reason why It works like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write the complete url in httpclient:

```
"https://hostname/api​/Cities​/region_cities​/region=" + regionId
```

Comment: This might not be needed if the received HttpClient instace (from `_api.Initial()`) contains a `BaseAddress`

Comment: @PeterCsala is correct, so thats not the trouble.